# Python: use apply on groups separatly after grouping dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My data frame looks like this:

```
┌────┬──────┬──────┐
│ No │ col1 │ col2 │
├────┼──────┼──────┤
│  1 │ A    │  5.0 │
│  1 │ B1   │ 10.0 │
│  1 │ B2   │ 20.0 │
│  2 │ A    │  0.0 │
│  2 │ B1   │  0.0 │
│  2 │ C1   │  0.0 │
│  3 │ A    │  0.0 │
│  3 │ B1   │  5.0 │
│  3 │ C1   │ 20.0 │
│  3 │ C2   │ 30.0 │
└────┴──────┴──────┘
```

First I used `groupby` to group the data frame by column No.

I would like to do three things now:

1. get a list of values from column No where `col2 == 0.0` in all rows of this group (in this case No.2)
2. get a list of No's where `col2 != 0.0` for `col1 == 'A'` but at least one other row of the group has `col2 == 0.0` (in this case No.3)
3. get a list of No's where minimum 1 row contains `col2 == 0.0` (No.2 and 3)

Sorry for asking three issues at once. Hope that is ok.

Thank you:)

Comment: Expected output are `3` lists? Or DataFrame? Can you add it to answer? Performance is important?

Comment: Please post the expected output for each item

Comment: `col2 != 0.0` is correct for second list?

Comment: Yes,  lists are fine, don't need the whole data frame, cause I just need the group numbers (1,2,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
g = df['col2'].eq(0).groupby(df['No'])
a = g.all()
a = a.index[a].tolist()
print (a)
[2]

b1 = (df['col2'].ne(0) & df['col1'].eq('A')).groupby(df['No']).any()
b2 = (df['col2'].eq(0) & df['col1'].ne('A')).groupby(df['No']).any()
b = b1 & b2
b = b.index[b].tolist()
print (b)
[]

c = g.any()
c = c.index[c].tolist()
print (c)
[2,3]
```

Another solution should be custom function for return boolean `DataFrame` and final create dictionary with 3 lists:

```
def f(x):
    a = x['col2'].eq(0)
    b1 = x['col2'].ne(0) & x['col1'].eq('A')
    b2 = a & x['col1'].ne('A')
    b = b1.any() & b2.any()

    return pd.Series([a.all(), b, a.any()], index=list('abc'))

m = df.groupby('No').apply(f)
print (m)
        a      b      c
No                     
1   False  False  False
2    True  False   True
3   False  False   True

fin = {x: m[x].index[m[x]].tolist() for x in m.columns}
print (fin)
{'a': [2], 'b': [], 'c': [2, 3]}
```

Comment: in second solution, b does not work. at least it does not find any when it should find hundreds (like it does in first solution)

Comment: Sorry, one question: why don't I need `a.any()` for `b2` in second solution?

Comment: @MaMo - You need it twice in `b1.any() & b2.any()` - need chain 2 mask to `b`. If add another `b.any()` get scalar value from array, what dont need.